# Is it possible to call a final object in Java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to call a final object which is declared in a method, in another method of the same class?

```
public class MyClass{

    public void description(){
        //something...
        //something..

        final HashMap<String,String> desc = new HashMap<String,String>();
    }

    public void call(){

    }
}
```

Can I call the object `desc` in function `call()`?

Comment: ..No, you can't, it can be used only in the method scope!

Comment: Isn't this best answered by creating code and testing it?

Comment: Also, you look to be confusing object with variable. An object can be passed around to where it is needed, even if it is tied to a final local variable

Comment: Thank you all for clearing my doubt. I'm just a beginner in Java and I'm testing some examples. I was just getting confused with tons of keywords.

Comment: In the future, please test first, show what your test results show within your question.  Show what searching you've done prior to asking. This site has question quality standards and you're going to want to read up on them if you plan to ask future questions. The [ask] and the [help] links can help you

Comment: @David You are right. I could have sworn that the variable was an instance variable. And please check the edits: it was nyclass when I first saw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as `final object` in java. What you declared is a final variable, or final reference. It means you cannot reassign this variable name within the scope. This says nothing about the object being referenced however. So you can pass this object as follows:

```
public class MyClass {

  public void description() {
    //something...
    //something..

    final HashMap<String,String> desc = new HashMap<String,String>();
    call(desc);
  }

  public void call(Map<String, String> desc) {
    // do something, may be desc.put(key, val);
  }
}
```